# Universal cover of a $3$-manifold is isometric to a cylinder

Tags: algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, covering-spaces

Let $(M^3,g)$ be a compact, connected and orientable Riemannian $3$-manifold with boundary. Suppose that the universal cover of $M$ is isometric to the right cylinder $\tilde{M} = D \times \mathbb{R}$, where $D$ is a geodesic ball of the round unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$. **Is it true to assert that** $M$ is isometric to $D \times \mathbb{S}^1(r)$, where $\mathbb{S}^1(r)$ denotes the round circle of radius $r$, for some $r > 0$?

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, you have to have $D=S^2$ since otherwise $\tilde{M}$ is incomplete which is impossible. The manifold $M$ need not even be homeomorphic to the product: It can be the total space of a nontrivial circle bundle over the projective plane.

---

Since in the edit you indicated that $M$ is a manifold with boundary, if the boundary is nonempty, $M$ has to be homeomorphic to $D\times S^1$, where $D$ is the closed 2-disk. However, it need not be isometric to a product, just take an infinite cyclic group $G$ acting on $D\times R$ freely and generated by a skew motion (with nontrivial rotational component). Then $M:= (D\times R)/G$ is not isometric to a product.

Comment: I am considering $M$ to have nonempty boundary.

Comment: A cover of a manifold with non-empty boundary always has non-empty boundary so it cannot be homeomorphic to $D \times \mathbb{R}$ if $M$ has non-empty boundary.

Comment: @NickL: Sorry, I cannot follow the logic of your comment. Of course a compact manifold with nonempty boundary can be covered by the product of a closed disk with the real line.

Comment: Oops, I assumed it was an open disk. You are right, thanks.